# Bittrex Market History Confusion

Tags: ethereum, market, bittrex

So I recently made a very small test order of Digix DAO in the Ethereum market (Using bittrex), and I noticed that it showed up in the Market History section.

It looked a little like this (NOT EXACT)

`BUY - RATE 0.0... - TOTAL 0.0... ......`

So I bought X DGD with Y Ethereum.

However, there was no SELL order to compliment my BUY order.

When I bought the Digix DAO, I bought it from a seller, who sold it to me. Why isn't his SELL order in the market history, but my BUY order is?

This also applies for the opposite: What does it mean when there is a SELL order with no BUY order to compliment it?

Comment: You should contact Bittrex to learn how to trade on their platform.

Answer (score 0):

SELL means someone sold at the bid price rather than creating an order that is higher than the market price.

BUY means that someone bought at the ask price rather than creating an order that is lower than the market price.

There is never a compliment between the two for exchange markets.